# .NET Authorization Rules - Allow All Users Inherited - v4.0 framework app pools

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, .net-framework-version

ok, I have removed the Default rule on the top of the webserver tree in iis 7.5. but all v2.0 app pool websites also show Allow all users inherited removed, but all v4.0 app pool websites still show the allow all users inherited.
So I did a test just to double check and created a website with v2.0 default app pool, no allow all users inherited, then I changed the app pool to v4.0 and low and behold allow all users inherited appeared in .NET Authorization.
how do I stop this from happening? has this happened to others? I do not want to all all users inherited on the website, but need to user v4.0 framework app pool

Comment: SOLVED: - in the framework64 remove or comment out <allow users="*"> from the web.config file in the windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0xxx folder.

Comment: and windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0xx\config folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove  from the web.config file in the windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0 and in the windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0 folders.

I was also told to look for it in the machine.config and the app.config files and then the web.config file in the website root folder and in any subfolders. (which in my case it was not in those)